# jQuery .toggle() How Can I do

Tags: jquery, toggle

I has made the jquery `.slideToggle` on my Menu **Link 2**

The Action is when I click on **Link 2** will have another div `slideup id=#div2`, in `#div2` will have link "Click Me Please".

I would like that I can click this link but when I move the mouse over the "Click Me Please" the `#div2` is gone.

**Please See in Action:** http://jsfiddle.net/u3888/22/ by the way if I can click the link on `#div2` and when I move the mouse to **Link 1** and **Link 3** I want `#div2` is gone Automatic.

Kindly suggest me where am i wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this JSFiddle Link:

http://jsfiddle.net/u3888/29/

And this is the code:

```
$("#menu_244 a").hover(function(){
    $("#div1").fadeIn();
    $("#div2").fadeOut();
});

$("#menu_244").mouseout(function(){
    $("#div1").fadeOut();
});

$("#menu_245 a").click(function(){
    $("#div2").slideToggle("slow");
});

$("#menu_246 a").hover(function(){
    $("#div2").fadeOut();
    $("#div3").stop().fadeIn(500);
    $("#menu_246").mouseout(function(){
        $("#div3").fadeOut();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

hey you have written wrong code for below event.

```
$("#menu_245").mouseout(function(){
$("#div2").fadeOut();});
```

you change fadeOut() of div2

instead you specify.

```
$("#menu_245").mouseout(function(){
$("#div1").fadeOut();});
```

After this change it wont automatically fadeOut until you click Link2.

check the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/u3888/27/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#menu_244 a").hover(function(){
    $("#div1").fadeIn();
    $("#div2").fadeOut();
    $("#div3").fadeOut();
});

$("#menu_245 a").hover(function(){
    $("#div1").fadeOut();
    $("#div3").fadeOut();
});

$("#menu_245 a").click(function(){
    $("#div2").slideToggle("slow");
});

$("#menu_246 a").hover(function(){
    $("#div1").fadeOut();
    $("#div2").fadeOut();
    $("#div3").stop().fadeIn("5000");
});
```